# Can we make Google Cloud Load Balance to retry request on error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

some times few instances just responding with error 5xx, i want to know if there's a solution to redirect the request to other instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the GCP LB docs, only timeouts are retried, and then only in special cases.  Error code responses are not retried.

To work around this, you can create an HTTP health check on the instance group ( there are also https, tcp & http2 health checks).

**Create the HTTP Health Check**

```
$ HOST_HEADER=www.example.com
$ gcloud beta compute health-checks create http hc-http-port-80 \
    --description="Simple HTTP port 80 health check" \
    --check-interval=5s \
    --timeout=5s \
    --healthy-threshold=2 \
    --unhealthy-threshold=2 \
    --port=80 \
    --host=${HOST_HEADER}
```

**Once created, you can associate it with your LB**

```
$ cloud compute backend-services update [BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME] \
    --region [REGION] \
    --health-checks [HEALTH_CHECK_NAME]
```

**Find the Backend Service ID**
If you don't know the name of your backend service, you can obtain it with this command

```
gcloud compute backend-services list \
    --filter="loadBalancingScheme=EXTERNAL" \
    --filter="protocol=HTTP"
```

Comment: Anthony, health checks will not cause the load balancer to retry failed requests. By the time a health check reports failure, many client requests could have failed during that time. Your solution for implementing health checks with the CLI is good.

Comment: You are correct. I discovered after the writeup that only timeouts are retried. I'll update the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what Anthony mentioned, and based on the official documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#timeouts_and_retries):

> "HTTP(S) Load Balancing retries failed GET requests in certain circumstances, such as when the response timeout is exhausted."

Here you can find an official guide of how to configure a response timeout [2](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#timeout-setting).

But what you are actually asking for is if after a retry the request could be sent to another instance.

There is no priority order on which instance will handle the request, the load balancer will send the request only to healthy backends. The choice of backend will on some parameters you define, like the CPU load. If the load balancer is responding with a 5xx it means that the are no healthy backend available.

You will need to work in mitigating those 5xx errors: Maybe the backends cannot handle the amount of load received, the webserver are not listening to the correct ports or maybe the healthchecks are not correctly configured.

---